# Get User Info after successful authentication using Windows Broker Authentication in Windows Metro App

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-runtime

I am working on Windows Broker Authentication.I can successfully authenticate in to the calling app and  can comeback to the home page after authentication.

I am not able to get the user info (username) .I have tried but I get one message as written below.

*A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll
WinRT information: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
Additional information: Unauthorized (401).
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.*

I have written my code below.Please friends help me.

```
  private const string RESOURCE_NAME ="id_token";

  public async Task<UserInfo> GetName(string accessToken)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("OAuth", accessToken);

                var result = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(loginUri));

                var profileInformation =JsonObject.Parse(result).GetObject();

                var name = profileInformation.GetNamedString("username");
                return new UserInfo { Name = name };
            }

            catch (JsonException ex)
            {
                throw new JsonException(ex.message);
            }




        }  

  private async void btnHomeLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string Scope = "openid profile";
        var client = new OAuth2Client(new Uri(loginUri));

        var startUri = client.CreateAuthorizeUrl(
            ClientID,
            RESOURCE_NAME,
            Scope,
            RedirectURI, 
            state,
            nonce);
        string Authresult;
        try
        {
            var webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, new Uri(startUri),new Uri(RedirectURI));

            switch (webAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus)
            {
                case Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationStatus.Success:
                    //Successful authentication.
                    Authresult = webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString();

                    UserInfo userInfo = await GetName(RESOURCE_NAME);


                    break;
                case Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp:
                    //HTTP error.
                    Authresult = webAuthenticationResult.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString();
                    break;
                default:
                    //Other error.
                    Authresult = webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString();
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Authentication failed. Handle parameter, SSL/TLS, and Network Unavailable errors here. 
            Authresult = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are exactly using the above code, then based on the above, you are calling GetName function with a constant string (RESOURCE_NAME) instead of the actual AuthResult (accessToken) that was returned from the webAuthenticationResult. If the intention of calling the WebAuthenticationBroker is to get back an Access Token which should later be used with HttpClient, then you need to adjust your code accordingly and make use of the right access Token when calling the HttpClient code. Otherwise the 401 is not unexpected if you are not passing the right token.

Comment: Hi Prasant ,  Thanks for your help. I can successfully authenticate by using that access token(RESOURCE_NAME) .But I can not get the logged in User info(Username,email id...) after successfully logged in and come back to my home page with the user info. Can you please hopefully provide me some help hints/suggestions.

Comment: If the HttpClient request is returning a 401 error, then it means that you are not using the right authentication headers and are getting denied access on the server. That means you don't have a response you can parse/are looking for. If you can emulate a successful request using tools such as Fiddler, I would suggest that you start with a working HTTP request first and understand what the request headers look like - specifically the format of the HTTP Authorization header and then recreate your HttpClient request using that raw HTTP request.